# In complex geometry, is an holomorphic function continuous by definition?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

I am attending a course on Introduction to Complex Geometry, and the definition they have given me of a holomorphic function between complex manifolds is as follows:

> Let $X,Y$ be complex manifolds. A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is $\textbf{holomorphic}$ if 1. f is continuous and 2. $\forall p\in X$, there exist charts $(U,\phi)$ in $X$, $(V,\psi)$ in $Y$ so that $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(U\cap f^{-1}(V)) \rightarrow \psi(V)$ is holomorphic.

My question is: Is the first hypothesis (f continuous) necessary? Does not the second one imply the first one? This question also applies to Differential Geometry in the real case. Does anyone know if there is a counterexample if the first hypothesis is removed? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to require that $p\in U$ and $f(p)\in V$ in point 2.

Comment: You should ask. It does not appear to be necessary.

Comment: It depends on your precise definition of a holomorphic/smooth function: Do you require the domain to be open? If not, then there are counter-examples which were discussed many times on MSE, most recently, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752948/are-these-two-definitions-of-smoothness-on-manifolds-equivalent?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for your help and the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : A \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ be a complex function, with $A \subseteq \Bbb{C}$. Usually, to even say that $f$ is holomorphic, we require that $A$ be an **open** subset of $\Bbb{C}$, just like with differentiability of real functions. It's not entirely obvious why, but I think it's standard.

So, in order to be able to say $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is continuous, we need its domain to be open. This requires $f$ to be continuous, because we need $f^{-1}(V)$ to be open.

Comment: It's standard because it gives rise to the best notion of differentiability. A lot of complex analysis would be false or meaningless for "holomorphic" functions which are differentiable when restricted to, I don't know, something weird like a Cantor set. We need local space about every point to have disks, local antiderivatives, sensible integrals, Cauchy-Riemann equations...

Comment: Thanks @FShrike for providing extra context!

Comment: One can say that a function whose domain is not open cannot be holomorphic. Then, if some of the above domains are not open, then $f$ is not holomorphic by default.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! :D